# How often does the FBI choose to investigate me?

Tags: makeitrain

Sometimes, almost randomly, almost seemingly when I get to high amounts of income does the FBI choose to investigate me, and I really don't like losing assets and cash value when the spinner lands on the wrong tile.  Is it possible to predict in advance or know when the FBI is coming so I can liquidate what current funds I have in either the political investment tree, the financial investment tree, or the last tree?

[image]

Comment: *insert joke about being added to the FBI watchlist*